Liquid Sim in a Closed Container Not Working
I'm trying to simulate an oil drum getting knocked over and liquid spilling out of it. Right now, my sim is not behaving as intended. When I move the sim out of the hollow drum model, it behaves as intended and simulates correctly. But inside of the drum, the liquid  doesn't emit much at all. This is what my drum model looks like: 
and this is what the sim is doing inside of it:

I've tried flipping the normals of the drum model and increasing the surface thickness but it didn't have any difference in behaviour. I have the drum as Effector Type: Collision, with sampling substeps at 4 and surface thickness as 0.7. The drum itself is moving as a child of a rigid body simulation. The liquid source is an Inflow fluid sim with the mesh as the flow source and 0.02 surface emission.
In case this is useful, this is what the inside of the drum looks like with the normals visible: 
Appreciate any guidance I can get, thank you!

I am going to try this myself tomorrow, but I'll try https://youtu.be/ZNb8I4v53-A?si=URqCtdG0sv-Yarae.
Basically inverting your normals to inside (as fas as I can tell the normal of your drum in inverted, but solidified or something because your inside is inverted too.) (edit mode-> face select-> all-> ⇧ Shift + N-> maybe inside, maybe not; you want the inside to be blue); then make a hole at the top and step up the domain resolution.
Then close the hole again. I‘d recommend watching the video, just to clarify, and maybe make it more obvious what I mean
